# SP2013 Central Admin Website disappear after moving the DB data file to another drive

Tags: 2013, central-administration

I asked DBA to move all the SP databases to D: drive instead of the default system drive C:

After that, I cannot access the Central Admin Website. In the IIS manager, the CA website disappeared as well as the application pool.

The CA site folder still exists in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDriectories

what is the proper way to restore the CA site?

Comment: I found this blog: http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2009/07/28/How-to-Recreate-your-Central-Administration-Web.aspx

Is the stsadm command still valid for 2013?

Comment: yes it is. I would reattach all those databases back to SQL in the same name they were in, then restart the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the IIS-Website for CentralAdmin shouldn't disappear just because the database gets lost. Do you have multiple SharePoint-Servers? Is it possible that CA was hosted on another one than you looked for?

To restore a broken CentralAdmin, i wouldn't recommend the STSADM-Command. It is still possible, but "todays" way is to provision it via SharePoint ProductsConfiguration Wizard or it's CMD-pendant psconfig.exe.

[image: This will reprovision CA on your Server]

Comment: Thanks. I ran the SP Config Wizard the CA website show up again.